# Remove the map function

Tags: javascript, promise

I have the following javascript promise, I'm looping through a list of documents, upload them one by one to Dropbox (API call), get back a shared link for each one of the documents, save them in an array and then generate an email with these links.

```
docs = self.checkedDocs();
body = "Please click on the link(s) below to view your document(s): ";
$.when.apply($, docs.map(function (doc) {
    return self.service.getDropboxLink(doc).then(function (dropboxLink) {
         return lineBreak + doc.documentDescription() + ": " + dropboxLink;
    });
})).done(function () {
    var attachment = [].join.call(arguments, '');
    formatEmail(attachment, body);
});
```

What I'm trying to do is the exact same thing but for only **one** document, I understand that I don't need the `map` anymore but I'm not sure how to do it.

Could you help?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something this is not a "JavaScript promise", it's a "jQuery promise". I strongly suggest you move on from jQuery promises (and jQuery itself, if at all possible). There is no need for them now, and they are broken in meaningful ways and at best non-standard.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "they are broken in meaningful ways"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$.when` construct is used precisely because you want to wait for several promises. With only one document, most of the complexity goes away:

```
self.service.getDropboxLink(doc).then(function(dropboxLink) {
     var attachment = doc.documentDescription() + ": " + dropboxLink;
     openEmail("Please click on the link below to view your document: ", attachment);        
});
```

Comment: (the question changed from using openEmail to formatEmail)

Comment: Working perfectly, thank you so much!! Also thank you for the explanation, now I really understand how it works! Thank you!